# Form Validation stays stuck on error Statement

Tags: javascript, forms, pug

So im validating some passwords with simple JS. i have an if statement if pw don't match add some css. But when i go back in the form and change the pw to match the errors stay no matter what. i added console logs and it looks like it just stays stuck in the first if and never moves to else. i tired it with and with out the return with no luck.

Javascript

```
 var passwordField = document.getElementById("password");
        var passwordConfirmField = document.getElementById("passwordConfirm");
        var form = document.getElementById("register");

        function validateForm(){

            if(passwordField.value != passwordConfirmField){
                console.log("error")
                document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "red";
                document.getElementById("passwordConfirm").style.borderColor = "red";
                $('#error').show();
                console.log("Show")
            }
            else {
                console.log("Pressing")
                form.submit();
                console.log("Submit")
                
            }
        }
```

PUG

```
block content
    .loginContainer 
        h1 Register
        form#register(method="post", onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateForm();")
            input(type="text", name="firstName", placeholder="First Name", required="")
            input(type="text", name="lastName", placeholder="Last Name", required="")
            input(type="text", name="username", placeholder="Username", required="")
            input(type="text", name="email", placeholder="Email", required="")
            input#password(type="password", name="password", placeholder="Password", required="")
            input#passwordConfirm(type="password", name="passwordConfirm", placeholder="Confirm Password", required="")
            .alert.alert-danger#error(role='alert')
                | Passwords Do Not Match
            input(type="submit", value="Register")
        a(href="/login") Already have an account? Login Here
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the condition in the `if` statement is wrong. It should be:

```
passwordField.value !== passwordConfirmField.value
```

Note: It's a good practice to use strict equality `===` over `==`, same for `!==` and `!=`

Comment: Cool i added that but when i retype the pw to match it stil persists as an error :(

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: do you have it in codepen where I can have a look?